# JAVASCRIPT: enlazar una funcion .js en un documento HTLM5

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Tengo un archivo .js que muestra la fecha y hora, un documento html en la que quiero que se me aparezca dicha fecha y hora. En la cabecera  enlazo con  el documento .js y hasta aquí todo bien, la fecha y hora se me aparece y funciona correctamente pero quiero que se pueda manejar dentro del cuerpo  la función para poder darle estilo.

Archivo reloj.js:

```
function textoFecha(fecha){

    var numDiaSem = fecha.getDay(); 


    var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
    var diaLetras = diasSemana[fecha.getDay()];   


    var meses = new Array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
    var mesLetras = meses[fecha.getMonth()]; 

    var diaMes = (fecha.getDate());   
    var anho = fecha.getFullYear();  
    var hora = fecha.getHours();    
    var min = fecha.getMinutes();  

    if ((min >= 0) && (min < 10)) {    //añadde un cero cuando los minutostienen 1 dígito.
      min = "0" + min;
    }

    var devolver = "Hoy es " + diaLetras+ ", " + diaMes + " de " + mesLetras + " de " + anho + " y son las " + hora + ":" + min + " horas.";
    return devolver;
  }
  var fecha = new Date();  
  document.write(textoFecha(fecha));  //Imprimir
```

El documento HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Germán Iglesias Ramos" />
    <meta name="description"
        content="Página principal de la pagina web dedicada a la distribución y venta de sidras y derivados" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="sidra, Sidra, sidreria, Sidreria, Sidrería, sidrería, sidras, culin, culín, escanciador, bebida
    corcho, botella, botellas, asturias, Asturias, chigre, escanciar, llagar, Llagar" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript" />
    <link rel="icon" href="IMG/iconoSidra.jpg" type="image/jpg" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JAVASCRIPT/analogico.js"></script>
    <script src="JAVASCRIPT/reloj.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/barraMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/estiloTitulo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="./CSS/analogico.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="./CSS/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>El Llagar Online</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="clockDate" title="Fecha" >
        <p id="date"></p>
    </div>
```

Es en la parte de abajo del documento HTML, dónde el elemento div  en el lugar que necesitaría poner una función, una entrada, algo... que haga referencia a dicho archivo reloj,js para poder darle estilo con una hoja CSS

Comment: puedes agregarle es estilo de forma normal solo debes hacer un `window.onload = init();` donde init(); sera la funcion que inicialize tu codigo esto es para que se ejecute una vez todo el documento este listo y no en orden con suele ejecutarlo el navegador de arriba a abajo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el script en lugar de `document.write(textoFecha(fecha));` utiliza `date.innerHTML = textoFecha(fecha);` o si prefieres:

```
let date = document.querySelector("#date");
date.innerHTML = textoFecha(fecha);
```

También una observación: Es mejor agregar los scripts justo antes de `</body>`.
Recomiendo leer [Como perder peso en el navegador. La guía definitiva para el rendimiento front-end](https://browserdiet.com/es/)

```js
function textoFecha(fecha){

    var numDiaSem = fecha.getDay(); 


    var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
    var diaLetras = diasSemana[fecha.getDay()];   


    var meses = new Array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
    var mesLetras = meses[fecha.getMonth()]; 

    var diaMes = (fecha.getDate());   
    var anho = fecha.getFullYear();  
    var hora = fecha.getHours();    
    var min = fecha.getMinutes();  

    if ((min >= 0) && (min < 10)) {    //añadde un cero cuando los minutostienen 1 dígito.
      min = "0" + min;
    }

    var devolver = "Hoy es " + diaLetras+ ", " + diaMes + " de " + mesLetras + " de " + anho + " y son las " + hora + ":" + min + " horas.";
    return devolver;
  }
  var fecha = new Date();  
 date.innerHTML = textoFecha(fecha);  //Imprimir
```

```css
#date{text-align:center;padding:2em; margin:1em; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<div id="clockDate" title="Fecha" >
        <p id="date"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no estoy loco los scripts no van en el head. Van al final del body (van en cualquier parte del body pero ponelos siempre al final por un tema de organización)

Comment: Es requisito en la app que desarrollo que estén en el head. El problema está en que no sé que funcion añadir en la parte de div para que me salga la fecha una sola vez y no dos

Comment: Ah si enlazas JS al head también puede leerlo? No estaba ni enterado

Comment: Seguro, lo lee.